# Progress bar powershell script doesn't work when called from a batch script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I am facing this situation where, when i run my powershell script from PowershellISE it works as desired. But when the same script is called from a batch file the part of the powershell script with a progressbar function is written, it shows no response. I am unable to find out what is it that i am missing.
The powershell script is :

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") | Out-Null


#FUNCTION- progress bar
function progress-bar {
$Runspace = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$PowerShell = [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell]::Create()
$PowerShell.runspace = $Runspace
$Runspace.Open()

[void]$PowerShell.AddScript({

$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.width = 1000
$Form.height = 200
$Form.Text = "text"
$Form.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Times New Roman" ,12, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Regular)
$Form.MinimizeBox = $False
$Form.MaximizeBox = $False
$Form.WindowState = "Normal"
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$ProgressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$ProgressBar.Maximum = 100
$ProgressBar.Minimum = 0
$ProgressBar.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,70)
$ProgressBar.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(967,10)
$ProgressBar.style = 'Marquee'
$MessagesLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$MessagesLabel.AutoSize = $true
$MessagesLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,45)
$MessagesLabel.Text = "message for user"

$ShownFormAction = {
    $Form.Activate()

   # $Form.Dispose()
}

$Form.Add_Shown($ShownFormAction)
$Form.Controls.Add($MessagesLabel)
$Form.Controls.Add($ProgressBar)

$Form.ShowDialog()

})
$PowerShell.BeginInvoke()
}
#begin main process
progress-bar
Get-Date
Start-Sleep 5
#end main process
```

and the batch file which i am using to call this above script contains:

```
echo off
SET HomeDir=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%HomeDir%
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%HomeDir%\1.ps1'";
exit
```

Please help with any pointer to solution.

Comment: Not 100% certain, but I would assume that CMD doesn't have the capacity to display the progress bar. It's a legacy part of windows that preserves backwards compatability, PowerShell was developed as it's replacement. Why are you running PS via a batch file? Any reason you don't just run the script directly?

Comment: The powershell script is for users which can run the script on their desktop.So they just need to double click the batch file to execute the ps script.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the start command in the batch script e.g.

```
start powershell.exe -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%HomeDir%\1.ps1'";
```

This will open the powershell process in a new window and close the batch behind it, hopefully ensuring that whatever features you're using should display properly.